# Call Ajax on a click event instead of document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call on document.ready function as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        function AjaxCall(HandleData) {
       return $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_up/",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
            {
              HandleData(data);
            }

    });
}
      AjaxCall(function(output){

        data = JSON.stringify(output);
```

I want to call this though on a click function of a div so that the Ajax call to server is made once i click on it instead of making the call on document.ready
How do I go about this?
I want to call it here

```
 $(".reply").click(function (){
```

I have tried to put it inside it like below

```
$(".reply").ready(function(){

            function AjaxCall(HandleData) {
           return $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax_up/",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                  HandleData(data);
                }

        });
    }
          AjaxCall(function(output){

            data = JSON.stringify(output);
```

Thanks

Comment: Your first code block looks nearly identical to the second. You mentioned a click handler: `$(".reply").click(function (){`. Where is that in your code?

Comment: Hi showdy, that was a typo in code..I actually use $(".reply").click(),any insights please?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".reply").on("click", function() {
        AjaxCall(function(output){
            data = JSON.stringify(output);
        }
    });
    function AjaxCall(HandleData) {
        return $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_up/",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                HandleData(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You're calling the `ready()` method on the `.reply` class, when you should simply keep the document ready handler, and assign the click method (I use `on()` just out of preference) to `.reply`, and call the `AjaxCall` method inside of said click handler.

Comment: Thanks RUJordan, with your example AjaxCall(function(output){

        data = JSON.stringify(output);
 doesn't seems to get the data.

Comment: You may not need to return the ajax call. Try some debugging to make sure the ajax script is returning data, make sure the url is correct, etc

Comment: With my original code, data is returned so am sure url etc is ok..but when am trying to adopt your example and alert(data), nothing appears